# TextMate grammar do I need a UUID for my grammar?

Tags: textmate

If I were to create a new TextMate grammar for a new HTML templating language, do I need to come up with my own UUID for my TextMate grammar?

For example, if my grammar looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "My Language",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "include": "<my rules here>"
    }
    {
      "include": "text.html.basic"
    }
  ],
  "scopeName": "<my scope name>",
  "uuid": <do I need to put something here?>
}
```

On the `uuid` key, do I need to provide a specific value? What is it used for?

I'm having trouble finding documentation about this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need a UUID. Fortunately it's very easy to create them.

Just run `uuidgen` in your terminal.

You can even do this within TextMate by entering `uuidgen` on a line and running the line with the bundle command "Shell Script" -> "Execute Line" or with the shortcut `^` + `r`.

I ran it a few times to answer this question, and would gladly offer these UUIDs for your use. Of course, since they're public, you can't assured no one else will come to this question and use them... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

7343A295-8B3D-4C09-BA03-3F8120152C34

F1ECD083-A81A-4937-B60E-1B4B83EA3B28

A35ED231-6816-4D4C-8E12-54A007854C29